# How to write a rule in Gitlab CI for running a job after merge to master?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to run a certain job on master branch after each merge to it. Pipelines that were scheduled or run manually should not contain this job. Is there a way to do that in GitLab CI?

As a side note, I want to say that I don't want to use "merge_request_event" because it triggers an additional pipeline after every commit to a merge request and it's something that doesn't suit me.
But it will also run while triggering a pipeline on master manually and I don't need that

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in you `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```yaml
job_name:
  script:
    - your_job_part_1
    - your_job_part_2
  only:
    - master
```

It will run you `job_name` each time master is updated, hence, each time a merge request is accepted and branch is merged into master.

You can take a look at [GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/) for more options.

Comment: But it will also run while triggering a pipeline on master manually and I don't need that

Comment: This was not mentioned in your question. Moreover, it is possible to use ```when: manual``` to run a job only launched manually but I don't know any way of doing the opposite.

Comment: Yeah, my bad it wasn't in the question. I need something like `when: merge_request` and `only: master`. But I guess there's no such thing, unfortunately

Comment: You should either accept my answer or modify your question accordingly for people looking for a similar question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rules` keyword:

```yaml
job_name:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'master' && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

You can also replace `master` string by `$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` variable if you master/main branch is the default.

See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#rules